# why my app is crashing when navigating through drawer?

Tags: java, android

I just started android development and my app is crashing when i navigate through drawer. here is my code that is edited in the navigation-drawer activity .

this is the thing i edited , I wanted new screen when some choose one of the items from drawer . i created 3 new layout(xml files) and want to display these

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.call) {

        setContentView(R.layout.phone);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    else if (id == R.id.message) {

        setContentView(R.layout.sms);

        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    else if (id == R.id.email) {

        setContentView(R.layout.email);

        et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);


        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);



    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Post logcat pls, with the error

Comment: `setContentView` should not be abused like that. Use Fragments, that's what they were made for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is crashing because you cannot use setContentView(R.layout.something).

First you need to make activity for each XML file. This is as simple to do as this:

```
public class Activity1 {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.phone);  //DO THIS FOR EACH XML LAYOUT
    }
}
```

Then don't forget another important thing, adding each activity to AndroidManifest.xml. Your manifest file probably already has something like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    //ADD NEXT 2 LINES FOR EACH NEW ACTIVITY YOU MAKE
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1">
</application
```

Then, the last thing you need to do is in your onNavigationItemSelected method.

Instead of setContentView(R.layout.something), do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If there is anything unclear in my answer, feel free to ask.

NOTE: This is if you want your app to change activities through navigation drawer. You might want to look into Fragments for a different approach.

EDIT: here is the link to Google's tutorial on activities:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

and here is the link to another example, which might be more understandable to you:

http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-within-the-same-application/

Comment: Thanks sir i learned it . now it works .  also tell me something to work with fragments in the same case .